# issue installing python 2.76 with homebrew on OSX mountain lion

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

I am doing a clean install of homebrew , python on OSX mountain lion.

this is what i have done so far...

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install)"
$ brew doctor
$ brew install readline sqlite gdbm --universal
```

this is all working but now i try to install python..

```
$ brew install python --universal --framework
```

I now get this error..

```
$ brew install python --universal --framework
==> Downloading http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tgz
######################################################################## 100.0%
Error: SHA1 mismatch
Expected: 8328d9f1d55574a287df384f4931a3942f03da64
Actual: 36a06fba4c5de9cc7338b5ca01bed976f7088b7b
Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/python-2.7.6.tgz
(To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.)
```

I have deleted the file and tried again. Same error. Does anyone have an explanation for this ? am i missing something obvious?. Is it possible for me to force home brew to go back a python version?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9883847/1193075

Comment: @MattDMo brew has worked for me without any problems, while MacPorts let me down on several occasions. I guess it depends on the packages you use.

Comment: i've tried 'brew update' and just tried the other fix suggested in stackoverflow.com/a/9883847/1193075 . I still get the same error. I'll consider switching to mac ports.

Comment: @uselpa - People's experiences with `port` vs. `brew` is really varied - I was really disappointed with `brew` (about a year and a half ago, haven't tried since) and overall have had great success with `port`, although occasionally there are issues, like with any package manager (`apt-get`, `yum`, etc.). Reading through [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com), though, maybe 50% of people have had the opposite experience, so I guess it just really depends on what packages you're interested in and how well they're maintained.

Comment: @MattW - Homebrew and MacPorts can be used at the same time, since `port` installs to `/opt/local/bin` (by default) while `brew` installs to `/usr/local/bin` - all you'd need to do is edit your `$PATH` to put one or the other directory first. Also, as a complete alternative, you could use the [python.org](http://python.org/download) version. YMMV :)

Comment: thanks for the advice @MattDMo and uselpa. I mostly use image/video libraries, opencv, pyside, imagemagic, openexr, and have generally found better support with brew. I'll give MacPorts a go again and attempt to use both when I find something i cannot get on MacPorts. -- I was hoping this may be an issue others were having with python 2.7.6, ..but it seems to be just my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading the file manually using `curl` and/or `wget`, and then run `sha1sum` on it.  Something might be falsifying the file as you download it.

Comment: Thank you very much sir!, 'wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tgz' . to download the tgz and '/usr/bin/openssl sha1 Python-2.7.6.tgz'. It had the correct hash now. Then copy that over the version in /Caches/Homebrew/ folder. Now the brew command works.