# Error: SHA1 mismatch, while installing openni2

Tags: homebrew, openni

I'm trying to install OpenNI2 with Homebrew, but midway I ran into this common issue "Error: SHA1 mismatch"

I tried the solution from another question that resembled this like

[SHA1 error when using brew installs's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857629/sha1-error-when-using-brew-install) `brew update` ; however it's already updated

I also did try to remove, as it instructed, the listed archive but I ran into the same problem.

running `brew doctor` didn't seem to give a good hint on a resolution.

**Preq.**

```
$ brew tap homebrew/science

$ brew tap totakke/openni2
```

**Action**

```
$ brew install openni2
```

**Output**

```
==> Downloading https://github.com/occipital/OpenNI2/archive/2.2-beta2.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://github.com/occipital/OpenNI2/pull/18.patch
######################################################################## 100.0%
Error: SHA1 mismatch
Expected: e0be30b6b9296939306155580df1ac7912d3f949
Actual: 4beb04a31a64677618801f0e95141807592442ef
Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/openni2--patch-e0be30b6b9296939306155580df1ac7912d3f949.patch
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
```

[reference](https://github.com/totakke/homebrew-openni2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause is hash mismatch of the [patch file](https://github.com/occipital/OpenNI2/pull/18.patch).

OpenNI2 formula is currently hosted by homebrew-science.
It's a homebrew-science problem.

Alternative solution is editting the formula by yourself.

```
$ brew edit openni2

- sha1 "e0be30b6b9296939306155580df1ac7912d3f949"
+ sha1 "4beb04a31a64677618801f0e95141807592442ef"
```

*Thanks Takeuchi!*

Comment: I encountered the issue when install cloud foundry-cli, it works after modified the valve...

Answer (score 0):

This means that the patch has changed since the formula was written. You should make sure that the patch has not been changed maliciously. If you trust the patch, you can run `brew edit openni2` to edit the formula, remove the `sha1` line corresponding to the patch, save the formula, and try again.